# Override UILabel's layout to add subviews with gesture handling

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I need to extend `UILabel` so that I can make parts of it clickable. For that, I need to subclass it and add transparent `UIView`s with tap handlers. The problem is, that since I don't know beforehand where the clickable area will be, I need to re-adjust those `UIView`s positions and maybe even their number, every time the text is resized/changed/laid out/etc. What is the appropriate method for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever your label needs to be laid out, [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews) will be called.  Override that and make your adjustments to your subviews after calling `super.layoutSubviews()`.

```
override layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    // Do additional work that needs to happen each time view layout happens
    ....
}
```